# SQL Server 64bit Linked Server to 32bit ODBC DSN source

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I have a Windows 7 64bit running SQL Server 64bit and I need to access data from DBF files stored in a local directory.
I've installed the Visual FoxPro drivers (32bit, the only available) to create a DSN with the 32bit version of ODBC utility (C:\Windows\SysWow64\odbcda32.exe).

Now I need to create a linked server but I can't make SQL Server see this 32bit DSN.

I've tried this solution after trying to make SQL Server directly use FoxPro drivers but I was not able to make it appear in the Provider list of the linked server creation form.

I also tried to manually register the vfpoledb.dll but I'm still non able to see this driver among Provider list choices.

Can you please help me.

Thanks in advance.
Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a 32 bit driver with a 64 bit application without something in the middle like an ODBC-ODBC Bridge which separates the architectures.